# Using on resize to set div height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this situation here. I have 2 divs left and right and the way it is working right now is that if the height of left div exceeds the height of the div on right, the function makes the heights equal and hide any extra text for the left div, which works fine for the most part but what is happening is that when i change the height of the window or test it on different screen size, it seems to mess up the height of the left div and also it doesn't set it back to the original height.

This is a [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vommyY) for demonstration. Simply change different screen sizes and then also exit out of responsive mode and you will see the issue.

```js
var leftContainer = document.getElementById('overflow_text')
var rightContainer = document.getElementById('offset_height')
var readToggle = document.getElementById('toggle_text')
var elem = document.querySelector('.readMore')
var fullText = elem.textContent;
var truncated = false;
var rightOffsetHeight = rightContainer.offsetHeight;
var leftOffsetHeight = leftContainer.offsetHeight;
console.log(leftOffsetHeight)
console.log(rightOffsetHeight)

function mounted() {
  if (leftOffsetHeight > rightOffsetHeight) {
    leftContainer.style.height = rightOffsetHeight + "px"
    readToggle.style.display = 'block'
    readToggle.innerHTML = 'Read More'
    while (leftContainer.scrollHeight > leftContainer.offsetHeight) {
      var wordArray = leftContainer.innerHTML.split(' ');
      wordArray.pop();
      leftContainer.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
      truncated = true
    }
  } else {
    readToggle.style.display = 'none'
  }
}


function showText() {
  if (truncated) {
    leftContainer.innerHTML = fullText
    leftContainer.style.height = 'auto'
    readToggle.innerHTML = 'Read Less'
    readToggle.style.position = 'relative'
    truncated = false
  } else {
    leftContainer.style.height = rightOffsetHeight + "px"
    while (leftContainer.scrollHeight > leftContainer.offsetHeight) {
      var wordArray = leftContainer.innerHTML.split(' ');
      wordArray.pop();
      leftContainer.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
      readToggle.innerHTML = 'Read More'
      truncated = true
    }
  }
}

function watchSize() {
  var w = window.outerWidth;
  var h = window.outerHeight;
  console.log(w)
  console.log(h)
}
```

```css
#toggle_text {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#offset_height {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad='mounted()' onresize='watchSize()'>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id='overflow_text' class="readMore">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
          vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
          Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices.Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum., nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum
          dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices.Maecenas nisl est, ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet,
          nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet,
        </p>
        <span id="toggle_text" onClick='showText()'>Read More</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="offset_height">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae sceula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue
          ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. scelerisque enim
          ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl estDonec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet,
          nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est.
          Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enimt.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hopefully someone is able to come up with some solution. That will help me out a ton. Thank you in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to adjust dev height onresize

```
new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#divId'), function(){ 
console.log('content dimension changed');
});
```

Comment: yeah i am trying to use just javascript. no jquery

Answer (score 0):

here is a javascript code

```
<script>
function resizeDivs() {
var main = document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
if (sidebar > main) {
    main = sidebar;
    document.getElementById('main').style.height = document.getElementById
('sidebar').style.height = main + 'px'
} else {
    sidebar = main;
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = document.getElementById
('main').style.height = sidebar + 'px'
}
}
window.onload = resizeDivs;
</script>
```

you may also [click here for more details](http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1504-how-to-dynamically-resize-div-elements-javascript/)